# Unsure how to solve equation

Tags: problem-solving

I have the problem. Solve: $x^3 - 3x^2 + 2x - 5 = 0$. I've done similar, simpler ones like this, but in this case I don't know. Can someone at least tell me what you'd even call this exact type of problem so I can google it and learn how to do this and work on it more?

Comment: Try looking into finding roots of polynomials.

Comment: [Cubic equations?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation). I must warn, roots aren't pretty.

Comment: This is a cubic equation. Lookup Tartaglia/Cardano.

Comment: Alright, thanks.

Comment: https://mediacru.sh/xdemgsRCo3xK

Comment: [The user O.L. has posted a general way of solving cubic equations.](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/539865/edit) He shows us that the [Cardano's formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicFormula.html) for a solution of the cubic equation $$x^3+ax^2+bx+c=0$$ is
$$\begin{align}
x=-\frac{a}{3}-\frac{\sqrt[3]{2}\left(-a^2+3b\right)}{3\sqrt[3]{-2a^3+9ab-27c+3 \sqrt{3}
\sqrt{4b^3-a^2b^2+4a^3c-18abc+27c^2}}}+\\
+\frac{\sqrt[3]{-2a^3+9ab-27c+3\sqrt{3}
\sqrt{4b^3-a^2b^2+4a^3c-18abc+27c^2}}}{3\sqrt[3]{2}}.
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to find all complex $x$ satisfying
$$x^3-3x^2+2x-5=0$$
First we want to remove the $-3x^2$ term, this can be done by doing the substitution $x=y+1$
$$(y+1)^3-3(y+1)^2+2(y+1)-5=0$$
Expanding this yields
$$y^3-y-5=0$$
Substitute $y=\frac\lambda z+z$, this also means that $z = \frac12\left(y+\sqrt{y^2-4\lambda}\right)$

$$-5-z-\frac\lambda z+\left(z+\frac\lambda z\right)^3=0$$

Multiply both sides with $z^3$ and collect in terms of $z$

$$z^6+z^4(3\lambda-1)-5z^3+z^2\left(3\lambda^2-\lambda\right)+\lambda^3=0$$

Substitute $\lambda=\frac13$ and then $u=z^3$

$$u^2-5u+\frac1{27}=0$$

Find the solution where $\pm$ is a $+$

$$u=\frac1{18}\left(45+\sqrt{2013}\right)$$

Substitute back $u=z^3$

$$z^3=\frac1{18}\left(45+\sqrt{2013}\right)$$

The cube root of that is $\frac{\sqrt[3]{45+\sqrt{2013}}}{\sqrt[3]{2}~3^{2/3}}$

Multiply that with the third roots of unity.

$$z=\frac{\sqrt[3]{\frac12\left(45+\sqrt{2013}\right)}}{3^{2/3}}$$
$$z=-\frac{\sqrt[3]{\frac12\left(-45-\sqrt{2013}\right)}}{3^{2/3}}$$
$$z=\frac{(-1)^{2/3}\sqrt[3]{\frac12\left(45+\sqrt{2013}\right)}}{3^{2/3}}$$

Substituting back for $z = \frac y2+\frac12\sqrt{y^2-\frac43}$

$$\frac y2+\frac12\sqrt{y^2-\frac43}=\frac{\sqrt[3]{\frac12\left(45+\sqrt{2013}\right)}}{3^{2/3}}$$
$$\frac y2+\frac12\sqrt{y^2-\frac43}=-\frac{\sqrt[3]{\frac12\left(-45-\sqrt{2013}\right)}}{3^{2/3}}$$
$$\frac y2+\frac12\sqrt{y^2-\frac43}=\frac{(-1)^{2/3}\sqrt[3]{\frac12\left(45+\sqrt{2013}\right)}}{3^{2/3}}$$

Solve the radical equation for $y$

$$y=\sqrt[3]{\frac2{3\left(45+\sqrt{2013}\right)}}+\frac{\sqrt[3]{\frac{45+\sqrt{2013}}{2}}}{3^{2/3}}$$
$$y=(-1)^{2/3}\sqrt[3]{\frac2{3\left(45+\sqrt{2013}\right)}}-\frac{\sqrt[3]{\frac{-45-\sqrt{2013}}{2}}}{3^{2/3}}$$
$$y=\frac{(-1)^{2/3}\sqrt[3]{\frac{45+\sqrt{2013}}{2}}}{3^{2/3}}-\sqrt[3]{\frac{-2}{3\left(45+\sqrt{2013}\right)}}$$

Substitute back $y=x-1$ and add $1$ to both sides

$$x=1+\sqrt[3]{\frac2{3\left(45+\sqrt{2013}\right)}}+\frac{\sqrt[3]{\frac{45+\sqrt{2013}}{2}}}{3^{2/3}}$$
$$x=1-(-1)^{2/3}\sqrt[3]{\frac2{3\left(45+\sqrt{2013}\right)}}-\frac{\sqrt[3]{\frac{-45-\sqrt{2013}}{2}}}{3^{2/3}}\approx$$
$$x=1+\frac{(-1)^{2/3}\sqrt[3]{\frac{45+\sqrt{2013}}{2}}}{3^{2/3}}-\sqrt[3]{\frac{-2}{3\left(45+\sqrt{2013}\right)}}$$

Here's some approximate versions of these numbers

$$
\begin{array}{rclcl}
x&\approx&2.90416085913492\\
x&\approx&0.04791957043254&-&1.311248044077123i\\
x&\approx&0.04791957043254&+&1.311248044077123i\\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Wow...I'm gonna bookmark this for... a long time from now. o_o;

Comment: I think you should include how you knew $x=y+1$ would work.